# Why does the officer think Jack would claim their efforts at the suspect's house?

Tags: plot-explanation, la-confidential

In *L.A Confidential* (1997), while facing temporary suspension as a technical advisor for the "Badge of Honor" show and
working in Vice, Jack and Exley visit the suspect's house, where two of their officers
is already present:

> Jack: What do you got?
>
> OFFICER: Three 12-gauge pumps, an empty box of double-aught buck, and
> some cash.
>
> Jack: So long, Vice. Badge of Honor, here I come.
>
> Officer: **Fu_k you, Vincennes. This is our collar**.

Here it suggests the officer is expressing anger or frustration towards Jack Vincennes and
claiming credit for the arrest or discovery of evidence.

Why does the officer think Jack would claim their efforts at the suspect's house?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What @blobbymcblobby says is true about rank, but to a large degree the officer's anger is simply in response to what Jack states:

> So long, Vice. Badge of Honor, here I come

So here, Jack is openly claiming that this bust will help him regain his status on Badge of Honor. He is openly claiming that he will get significant credit for this. It is hardly surprising that the officer gets angry at this.

Comment: yeah, forgot about that, pretty arrogant of him.

Answer (score 1):

Rank.

You forgot the bit after:

> EXLEY
>
> Quiet.  I'm ranking officer here.
> We go as a team.  End of story.

And they probably know Jack's not very wholesome too, but Exley, on the side of Jack, out ranks them, and could say whatever he wants.